# jQuery slim package fadeIn

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, show, fadein

I'm using jQuery SLIM packages and want to do this:

```
$(this).find('.card-body').fadeIn();
```

But I got `fadeIn(...) is not a function`.

I know that this not working on slim package.

how can I use fadeIn or some thing like it on this package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the full version of jQuery includes animation effects. Either download that or you could use CSS to achieve the same effect.